# Asterisk determine which phone number was answered when making simultaneous calls?

Tags: asterisk

I am using asterisk to make a phone call to multiple numbers simultaneously using

Dial(SIP/XXXXX&SIP/YYYYY&SIP/ZZZZZ)

This will call all three numbers at once and which ever one picks up first gets connected and other are hung up.

What I am trying to work out is there anyway in the dial plan to determine which of those numbers was the one that answered?

Little bit more information:

What happens is that a call comes in from outside DID number over SIP, I look up in my database and get a list of numbers to call at once (again outside PSTN type numbers) which the system rings using above.

XXXX could be 0712345678@provider

YYYY Could be 0412345678@provider

etc

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following variables to obtain that information:

`${DIALEDPEERNAME} * Dialed peer name
${DIALEDPEERNUMBER} * Dialed peer number`

The first will hold the name of the peer that was used - if you are dialing to a SIP device, that is what you're looking for. If you dialed using a carrier, you will need to use the second.

Good luck.

Comment: I'll give that ago soon, cheers. Will let you know how it turns out.

Answer (score 0):

one way to do this is look at CDR disposition and dstchannel values, like this:

exten=>h,1,NoOp( -- ${CDR(disposition)} -- ${CDR(dstchannel)} -- )

Comment: Unfortunately this is only giving me the channel identifier and not the number that was called.

`NoOp("SIP/*providename*-00000000", " -- NO ANSWER -- SIP/*providename*-00000001 -- ")`

What I am really hoping to get is 0712345678 or 0412345678

Comment: You can add U or M to Dial options, which will move the call to context you define once the call is answered. There you can set a variable and after the call ends check it in the exten=>h. Check this example http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=88570